# Magento category description

Tags: magento, categories, product, magento-1.9

I have the following problem.
My category description above (before the goods).
I wish to change the location of the category description. This should be at the bottom (after the goods).
I am using magento commerce 1.9

Comment: can you add a screen-shot, that what exactly you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the category template, which should be in your theme directory here;

```
app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

Where XXX YYY is the directory of the template you are using.  If there is no view.phtml file in there, magento will fall back to the base version here;

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

I suggest you copy it to your theme directory if it wasnt there.

Now, open that file and find this;

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And simply move it to the end of the file.