# Magento 1.7 - Move Category & Sub-Category Description After Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, categories, product

I want to move my Descriptions from existing - Top of the Page to - After Products
I have referred to the Solution for this at various Forums but none of them Worked.
The Easiest One I could find and implement too was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082587/magento-category-description/31446693#31446693) . But this resolution also did not work.
Kindly help in this regard.

PARTIALLY SOLVED:
I pasted this at the end of the code in /app/design/frontend/default/XXYY/template/magenthemes/filter/filter_content_wrapper.phtml :

categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>

Having said this, there is 1 Problem, the Description is now appearing at 2 Locations - Above the products and below the products.

Looking for further resolution on this

Comment: what ever PixieMedia has posted is correct. By the way whats the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: Well the description does not move down and instead remains above the products

Comment: first try printing something does it reach to your template ?

Comment: Rajat.. I am very new to the world of code. Could you help me re-frame your question for me to understand

Comment: ok can you try <?php echo '11111'; exit; ?> on top of your file ? and try refreshing page on to the browser

Comment: Did that.. Upon Refresh - I could not observe any changes

Comment: so you are not making changes in the right file. Now login to magento admin. Go to system->configuration nd from LHS menu find developer and click developer. Change your store and from current config scope and then expand debug and enable Template Path Hints and save. Then refresh your webpage and find the correct phtml file

Comment: Rajat.. Apologies for the delayed response. I tried and found the path to 
app/design/frontend/default/XXYY/template‌​/XYY/filter/filter_content_wrapper.phtml As per the link posted along with the Question, the Category Code is to be pasted towards the end of the code. However, originally too the code is at the end.

Comment: @rajatsaurastri have a look at my Partial Solution alongside my Question above. Help me out if you have any further clue on this.

Comment: remove the first description and you all set :)

Comment: @rajatsaurastri .. Well.. Sometimes things are right in front of us and we tend to complicate it further for no reason. - Fixed It.
The Extra Code I mentioned was not at all required.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Thanks rajat

Here is how I did it:
IMPORTANT: DO NOT USE THE FILE PATH HERE OR GIVEN UNDER ANY POSTS - IT IS THEME DEPENDENT

1) Use Template hints to identify the Category Description File Path
2) Now to shift your Description: Just find and Paste this code from the file towards the end and Save:

getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    
        categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>

NOTE: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content');  ?>` should be right above the Category Description Code